# how to communicate lynmotion ssc32 servo controller module with ROS(indigo)?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on lynmotion ssc32 servo controller module how to communicate this module with ROS(indigo)
i tried to communicate through given script and rebuild the  package successfully but i have no idea how this can be used as middleware between lynxmotion AL5D Arm and ROS
looking forward to your answer
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252183/how-to-communicate-lynmotion-ssc32-servo-controller-module-with-ros(indigo)??/) by [fahadhassan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29080/fahadhassan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out https://github.com/smd-ros-devel/lynxmotion_ssc32

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2017-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fahadhassan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29080/fahadhassan/) on 2017-02-16**:
but i m not understanding how to move servo with this package with ssc32 controller ....??
how to give angles to the servo with ssc32 controller using this package....??
please help me.........